# Are the finite quantum permutation groups, weakly group-theoretical?

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, fusion-categories

Wang defined in [Quantum symmetry groups of finite spaces](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1637425) a notion of quantum automorphism group. The application to a finite space of $n$ elements is called *the quantum permutation group of $n$ symbols*, and its quantum subgroups are called *quantum permutation groups of degree $n$*. See [Quantum permutation groups: a survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612724) by Banica–Bichon–Collins for a survey on this notion. We are interested here in the finite quantum permutation groups, see the classification for $n=4$ in [Quantum permutation groups acting on 4 points](https://banica.u-cergy.fr/pdf/qfp.pdf) by Banica–Bichon. Note that *finite* means finite dimensional as a Hopf $\mathrm C^*$-algebra.

Let $K$ be a finite quantum group. Then $\operatorname{Rep}(K)$ is a unitary integral fusion category. Let us call $K$ *weakly group-theoretical* if $\operatorname{Rep}(K)$ is so, i.e., if it has (up to equivalence) the same Drinfeld center as a sequence of group extensions. It is an open problem whether there exists an integral (complex) fusion category which is not weakly group-theoretical (see Question 2 of [Weakly group-theoretical and solvable fusion categories](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2010.06.009) by Etingof–Nikshych–Ostrik), so in particular, whether there exists a finite quantum group which is not so.

**Question**: Are the finite quantum permutation groups, weakly group-theoretical?

Note that there exists finite quantum groups which are not quantum permutation groups (the smallest example has dimension $24$; see [Finite quantum groups and quantum permutation groups](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2900441) by Banica–Bichon–Natale). Moreover, by the [paper of ENO](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2010.06.009) cited above, every finite quantum group of dimension less than $84$ is weakly group-theoretical.

This post was inspired by a question asked by J.P. McCarthy in [this talk](https://youtu.be/WbV6yAfgP2I).